# Zebra ZPL wrap text

Tags: word-wrap, zpl

I have to print a variable text in a field block of a ZPL label.

I would like to know if it is possibile to define block width and then automatically wrap text or if it is not possible and I have to manually add a new line char or split the text in two blocks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use the ^FB – Field Block command in the [manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf)

Comment: I was using ZebraDesigner and I did not find this command available!

Comment: I've noticed the same thing.  Most label design software does not make use of this command.